# Redirection plugin - how to let the editor access the 'redirection' menu?

Tags: plugins, redirect

I'm using the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). It enables a 'Redirection' submenu under "Tools" menu in Admin panel. As an Administrator I can access the plugin. But I want to avail it for my 'editor' accounts too.

I've searched a lot, but found solution like [this](http://develop.serialdesigngroup.com/wordpress/redirection-plugin-editor-role-access) that are offering solution like editing the plugin itself. I actually don't want to edit plugin files directly, as on next update all the changes will wipe out.

So, how can I let the 'editor' get access to the 'Redirection' submenu under 'Tools' menu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Update 2020

The original answer was of 2015, and the author has no affiliation with the plugin, so not aware of any changes to the plugin at all. You are requested to follow any updated helpful answer that might help you on this issue.

## Original Answer

Good news is, from version 2.3.7 of Redirection plugin, they introduced a filter called `redirection_role` for the privilege. Here's is the [core code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/redirection/tags/2.3.5/redirection.php) (v.2.3.7):

```
add_management_page( __( "Redirection", 'redirection' ), __( "Redirection", 'redirection' ), apply_filters( 'redirection_role', 'administrator' ), basename( __FILE__ ), array( &$this, "admin_screen" ) );
```

###Solution
Just put the following code into your theme's `functions.php` to enable 'editor' to get access to the 'Redirection' submenu:

```
/**
 * Redirection Plugin Editor access
 */
add_filter( 'redirection_role', 'redirection_to_editor' );
function redirection_to_editor() {
    return 'edit_pages';
}
```

See [Editor user role and capabilities in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) - WordPress Codex

Comment: This answer needs to explain how to give access to a specific path in the Tools menu, else the editor cannot find the Redirection page.

Comment: The Redirection plugin documentation says how to do this: https://redirection.me/developer/permissions/ and gives a lot more details.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @mayeenul-islam is very useful but I don't have enough rep points to vote or comment on it.

Since that answer was published, the Redirection plugin uses REST-API and this can give permission errors even though the function allows access to Editors.

In my case, using Redirection version 3.5, I solved the problem by changing the REST-API setting in the Redirection Options from 'Default /wp-json' to 'Proxy over Admin AJAX'.